# CouchDB data modeling for private user data

Tags: database-design, couchdb

I'm interested in using couchdb to build a private forum-like application. I think I've wrapped my head around how to model all the shared data (posts, topics, etc). My plan is:

- Each group gets its own DB
- Users in the group can post top-level "topic" documents. All users in the group can submit "comment" documents that will be linked to a topic as described [in this post](http://www.cmlenz.net/archives/2007/10/couchdb-joins).

I'd like to track when users have unread topics and comments and also let them flag certain documents as "favorites". This data needs to be private so it can't be stored in the group database. Is there an efficient way to retrieve this info from a per-user database when retrieving the documents from the group database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question is basically just asking about authorization, start with the [Security Features Overview](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview) and continue on to read about [Document Update Validation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Validation)  Then head over to the [CouchDB Book](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/index.html) and read it all.

Re your design question, there are way too many ways to go, all of which are heavily dependent on your specific application that it's impossible to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I've read a bunch of them already, but not the whole book yet. I clarified my question so hopefully it's more clear.